# Delphi OleContainer for WPS

Tags: delphi, ole, wps

we can write the below code to embed the MS Word in a Delphi application.
OleContainer1.CreateObject('Word.Document', False);
OleContainer1.DoVerb(0);

I am trying to write a code to use WPS document in a Delphi application. For Ex.

OleContainer1.CreateObject('WPS.Document', False);
OleContainer1.DoVerb(0);

But it is not working. can you please help how to create object for WPS in Delphi OLE container?

Using Delphi Berlin and Delphi 2010

Comment: Do you want to open a *.wps file? Can't MS Word open these?

Comment: No I want to open word files by using WPS olecontainer

Comment: So you want to open *.docx files?

Comment: Yes Thats right

Comment: Then why don't you want to use a MSWord container?

Comment: We thought of providing a both containers based on the user's wish. our plan is to pop-up which container they want. If they want to use WPS then open WPS container otherwise MS Word container

Comment: That is you want to open an embedded Microsoft Works if the users wants that?

Comment: Yes Thats right

Comment: I'd guess that there is no OLE interface to MS Works and you're out of luck. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OleContainer1.CreateObjectFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName, false);
```

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/TOleContainer_(Delphi)